# Plot the longest transcript in GenomicRanges with ggbio

Tags: r, genomicranges

I am trying to plot an specific region using `ggbio`. I am using the below code that produced my desire output, except that it contains several transcript. Is it possible to only plot the longest transcript? I've not been able to access the genomic ranges object within `Homo.sapiens` that I assume contains this information.

```
library(ggbio)
library(Homo.sapiens)

range <- GRanges("chr10"  , IRanges(start = 78000000 , end = 79000000))
p.txdb <- autoplot(Homo.sapiens, which = range)
p.txdb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that involves filtering `TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene` on the longest transcript by `gene_id` (which does remove genes without `gene_id`):

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    invisible(lapply(c("ggbio", "biovizBase", "data.table", 
        "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene", 
        "org.Hs.eg.db"),
        require, character.only = TRUE))})
txdb <- TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene

# retrieve transcript lengths
txlen <- transcriptLengths(txdb, with.utr5_len=TRUE, with.utr3_len=TRUE)
setDT(txlen)
txlen$len <- rowSums(as.matrix(txlen[, .(tx_len, utr5_len, utr3_len)]))
setkey(txlen, gene_id, len, tx_id)

# filter longesttranscript by gene_id
ltx <- txlen[!is.na(gene_id)][, tail(.SD,1), by=gene_id]$tx_id

# filter txdb object
txb <- as.list(txdb)
txb$transcripts <- txb$transcripts[txb$transcripts$tx_id %in% ltx, ]
txb$splicings <- txb$splicings[txb$splicings$tx_id %in% ltx,]
txb$genes <- txb$genes[txb$genes$tx_id %in% ltx,]
txb <- do.call(makeTxDb, txb)

# plot according to vignette, chapter 2.2.5
range <- GRanges("chr10", IRanges(start = 78000000 , end = 79000000))
gr.txdb <- crunch(txb, which = range)
#> Parsing transcripts...
#> Parsing exons...
#> Parsing cds...
#> Parsing utrs...
#> ------exons...
#> ------cdss...
#> ------introns...
#> ------utr...
#> aggregating...
#> Done
colnames(values(gr.txdb))[4] <- "model"
grl <- split(gr.txdb, gr.txdb$gene_id)
symbols <- select(org.Hs.eg.db, keys=names(grl), columns="SYMBOL", keytype="ENTREZID")
#> 'select()' returned 1:1 mapping between keys and columns
names(grl) <- symbols[match(symbols$ENTREZID, names(grl), nomatch=0),"SYMBOL"]
autoplot(grl, aes(type = "model"), gap.geom="chevron")
#> Constructing graphics...
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit:**
To get gene symbols instead of gene (or transcript) ids, just replace the names of grl with the associated gene symbols, e.g. via `org.Hs.eg.db`, or any other resource that matches them up.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `Homo.sapiens` as this object contains gene names. I couldn't find the gene names on `txDb` objects. Do you know how to add gene names?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help. One last thing, is there a way to reduce the size of the gene labels, without reducing the size of the genes? It's because I am plotting the genes together with a regional manhattan plot on top and the gene labels appear huge.

Comment: I have found no easy way - you would have to edit the `GGbio` object: replace last line with `p <- autoplot(grl, aes(type = "model"), gap.geom="chevron"); p@ggplot$layers[[8]]$aes_params$size <- 1.5; p` (default is 3; replace the chosen 1.5 with whatever fits in your case)

Comment: I am struggling to plot a region which looks quite different when plotting as usual, or by the longest transcript. I think it must have something to do with the fact that the genes don't have a `gene_id`. Is there any other way to filter them so that I don't lose so many genes within the region: chr6:29000000-33000000?